# Flink connector with Confluent Cloud without schema registry

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, confluent-cloud

I'm trying to run KafkaGettingStartedJob from https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-kinesis-data-analytics-java-examples repo. It is running fine while connecting with AWS MSK. I'm facing issues while running the same with Confluent Cloud. I have modified it to simply read data from one topic and write to other. I'm using following properties:

```
    properties.put("topic", "test");
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "xxx.aws.confluent.cloud:9092");
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "product_affinity");
    properties.setProperty("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
    properties.setProperty("sasl.mechanisms", "PLAIN");
    properties.setProperty("sasl.username", "XXX");
    properties.setProperty("sasl.password", "YYY");
    properties.setProperty("sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \n " +
            "serviceName='Test1' \n" +
            "username='XXX' \n" +
            "password='YYY';");
    properties.setProperty("client.dns.lookup","use_all_dns_ips");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "demo-consumer-1");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```

While running the flink job I'm getting following error after 1 minute of start of job:

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:116)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:78)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:192)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:185)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:179)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:503)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:386)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor143.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:284)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:199)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:74)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:152)
at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
```

Comment: The timeout is either because of a network or SASL misconfiguration. You should try to reproduce with a regular client to rule out a Flink issue, as well

Comment: @OneCricketeer Regular kafka client is working properly with same SASL configurations. But i can't use the regular client in my application

Comment: @Shubham any chance you can post full code? I'm trying to figure out how to write to confluent cloud from flink via having a  flink sink

Comment: @dplante Hey sorry, missed this comment. Do you still need the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after a lot of effort, found out that I had a typo in setting `sasl.mechanism` property. Mine was `sasl.mechanisms`. This link https://discourse.snowplowanalytics.com/t/kafka-confluent-cloud-authentication/4888 saved my day.

Comment: This is why you [use the enums, not strings](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/config/SaslConfigs.html#SASL_MECHANISM). Regular client should have had the same issue, like I said

Comment: True and thanks for pointing out the most probable reason. Still i think this property is misspelt somewhere on internet as i just copied it and the issue was so microscopic that couldn't be found easily with naked eye.

Comment: I think `mechanisms` was deprecated around Kafka 1.0 if I'm reading the Javadoc correctly